# how to take WordPress out of development mode?

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

I've got a WordPress folder, with SQL file already in it, as well as all the custom pages. I want to know how do you take WordPress out of development mode?

Comment: Can you elaborate your question for even better understanding. At the moment its like too vague to provide you any solution.

Comment: Are you using redux ?

Answer (score 0):

It seem that you're using the [redux framework](https://reduxframework.com/), to disable the development mode use the [Redux Developer Mode Disabler](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redux-developer-mode-disabler/) plugin:

> Redux is a really powerful framework. To make it easier for devs, we
>   built in a commit notice to our repo. Unfortunately, some devs are
>   shipping with those notices enabled. So that's why this plugin exists.
>   It will **turn off Developer Mode completely** for all instances of Redux.

Comment: You install it as a plugin